# How can I return to a line inside my While loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, escaping

This is just partial code:

```
def . . .:
    while True:
        raw_input_1
        if :
            break
        elif 'n':
            raw_input_2 ()
                if :
                    some condition
                    print
                elif some condition:
                    function                    
                else:
                    print "Invalid command."
```

**Question:** When the code hits "Invalid command." it returns to while True. What I want it to do is return to raw_input_2. Any suggestions?
I actually ended up solving this by inserting a second while True statement and some breaks as shown below, but I suspect this is wasted coding and I'm looking for something more direct & elegant.

```
def . . .:
    while True:
        raw_input_1
        if :
            break
        elif 'n':
            while True:
                raw_input2 ()
                if :
                    some condition
                    break
                    print
                elif some condition:
                    function
                    break
                else:
                    print "Invalid command."
```

Comment: You can't; there is no 'jump' or 'goto' in Python. Restructure your logic, like you did by inserting an extra `while` loop.

Comment: Using second `while` is OK. If you need you can put full second `while` in separated function to make it more readable.

Comment: If an input of `n` is the only thing that avoids breaking it out of the outer loop, I'd use `if x != "n": break`; then the second while loop doesn't need to be part of an `elif` clause, since it will just run as a result of not exiting the outer loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There isn't a `goto` in the core language, but you can install a module providing `goto` (and `comefrom`): [goto for Python](http://entrian.com/goto/). (It's a _working_ april fool's joke.)

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of the joke `goto` :-) but it's still a packaged restructuring of the logic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def . . .:
while True:
    raw_input_1
    if :
        break
    elif 'n':
        while True:
            raw_input_2 ()
                if :
                    some condition
                    print
                elif some condition:
                    function                    
                else:
                    print "Invalid command."
```

one more line "while" will do, without restructure your code. However, about the logic your want, an infinite loop without break process is not recommended to be in your code

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an extra while loop

```
def . . .:
    while True:
        raw_input_1
        if :
            break
        elif 'n':
            condition_ok = False
            while not condition_ok:
                raw_input_2 ()
                if :
                    some condition
                    print
                    condition_ok = True
                elif some condition:
                    function                    
                    condition_ok = True
                else:
                    print "Invalid command."
```

Then you can set `condition_ok` to break out of the while loop if the command is ok. Of course this approach has too much nesting to be considered "pythonic", and so I'd recommend you further break this down into functions.

Comment: What's the upside of that additional flag `condition_ok` compared to the `while True` and simply `break` out of that loop?

Comment: You can do either. It's contested whether `while True` and `break` are "cleaner", but I've seen good arguments from both sides.